# How to modify a payment form in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a food delivery web page with the wordpress restropress plugin,
the page looks like this: https://restropress.magnigenie.com/demo/food-items/

And the problem I have is that in the checkout form I want to remove the city field
since being a delivery I obviously only make deliveries in my city
and I don't want my customers to go through that redundancy.
I would also like to change the postcode field from text to a drop-down.

I have tried with some action hooks setting as "unset" the field "city" but nothing.
In the html of the page I managed to make the changes directly
but when I updated the plug-in changes were lost.

Can you help me? This is the plugins code that I'm trying to modify:

```
<fieldset id="rpress_checkout_order_details">
    <legend><?php echo apply_filters( 'rpress_checkout_order_details_text', esc_html__( 'Order Details', 'restropress' ) ); ?></legend>
    <?php do_action( 'rpress_purchase_form_before_order_details' ); ?>
    <?php
        if( rpress_selected_service() == 'delivery' ) :
            $customer  = RPRESS()->session->get( 'customer' );
            $customer  = wp_parse_args( $customer, array( 'delivery_address' => array(
                'address'       => '',
                'flat'          => '',
                'city'      => '',
                'postcode'  => '',
            ) ) );

            $customer['delivery_address'] = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $customer['delivery_address'] );

            if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

                $user_address = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_rpress_user_delivery_address', true );

                foreach( $customer['delivery_address'] as $key => $field ) {

                    if ( empty( $field ) && ! empty( $user_address[ $key ] ) ) {
                        $customer['delivery_address'][ $key ] = $user_address[ $key ];
                    } else {
                        $customer['delivery_address'][ $key ] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
            $customer['delivery_address'] = apply_filters( 'rpress_delivery_address', $customer['delivery_address'] );
    ?>
        <p id="rpress-street-address" class="rp-col-md-6 rp-col-sm-12">
            <label class="rpress-street-address" for="rpress-street-address">
                <?php esc_html_e('Street Address', 'restropress') ?>
                <span class="rpress-required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="rpress-input" type="text" name="rpress_street_address" id="rpress-street-address" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Street Address', 'restropress'); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['delivery_address']['address']; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p id="rpress-apt-suite" class="rp-col-md-6 rp-col-sm-12">
            <label class="rpress-apt-suite" for="rpress-apt-suite">
                <?php esc_html_e('Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)', 'restropress'); ?>
            </label>
            <input class="rpress-input" type="text" name="rpress_apt_suite" id="rpress-apt-suite" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Apartment, suite, unit etc. (optional)', 'restropress'); ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['delivery_address']['flat']; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p id="rpress-city" class="rp-col-md-6 rp-col-sm-12">
            <label class="rpress-city" for="rpress-city">
                <?php _e('Town / City', 'restropress') ?>
                <span class="rpress-required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="rpress-input" type="text" name="rpress_city" id="rpress-city" placeholder="<?php _e('Town / City', 'restropress') ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['delivery_address']['city']; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p id="rpress-postcode" class="rp-col-md-6 rp-col-sm-12">
            <label class="rpress-postcode" for="rpress-postcode">
                <?php _e('Postcode / ZIP', 'restropress') ?>
                <span class="rpress-required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="rpress-input" type="text" name="rpress_postcode" id="rpress-postcode" placeholder="<?php _e('Postcode / ZIP', 'restropress') ?>" value="<?php echo $customer['delivery_address']['postcode']; ?>" />
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p id="rpress-order-note" class="rp-col-sm-12">
    <label class="rpress-order-note" for="rpress-order-note"><?php echo sprintf( __('%s Instructions', 'restropress'), rpress_selected_service( 'label' ) ); ?></label>
    <textarea name="rpress_order_note" class="rpress-input" rows="5" cols="8" placeholder="<?php echo sprintf( __('Add %s instructions (optional)', 'restropress'), strtolower( rpress_selected_service( 'label' ) ) ); ?>"></textarea>
  </p>
    <?php do_action( 'rpress_purchase_form_order_details' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'rpress_purchase_form_order_details_fields' ); ?>
</fieldset>
```

I put this following hook in the functions.php file and it didn't work:

```
function wp_edit_checkout_fields($fields){

    unset($fields['delivery_adress']['city']);

    return $fields;

}

add_filter('rpress_purchase_form_order_details_fields', 'wp_edit_checkout_fields');
```

Comment: So did you place your custom code somewhere in theme’s `function.php` file?

Comment: Tou should provide the code in your question so the community can see your attempts. Please update your question.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Yes, in the functions.php file I put the hook with an unset for the city field (I updated my question with the plugin code for what it's worth) but the whole form disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: @Aliqua I've already updated it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Note that, there is `do_action( 'rpress_purchase_form_order_details_fields' );` in the plugin code. It is usually used with `add_action`, but not with `add_filter`.

Maybe you could take advantage of this filter call:

```php
$customer['delivery_address'] = apply_filters( 'rpress_delivery_address', $customer['delivery_address'] );
```

Try something like this (put in your `function.php` file):

```php
function your_custom_function($delivery_address) {
    // Try to somehow process the city field here...
    
    // First, you could output a variable
    // to understand the data structure
    print_r($delivery_address);

    // and return the changed address
    return $delivery_address;
}
add_filter( 'rpress_delivery_address', 'your_custom_function' );
```

Docs - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/